# multiple filterpredicate in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

So i am trying to implement multiple filter, one for searching only in username while other in searching in every field

```
 export class MemberComponent implements OnInit {
      dataSource;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'username', 'email', 'buttons'];
      listItems = ["Bret", "Antonette", "Samantha", "An"];
      constructor(private memSer: MemberService) { }

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.memSer.getMember().subscribe(
          (data) => {
            //this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
              (data: Element, filter: string) => {
                return data['username'].trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
              }

          }
        )

      }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue);
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
  searchFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue);
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
```

searchfilter is supposed to search in every field while applyfilter in only username, Is this possible in angular mat 5?

Here's HTML

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="ID" (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of listItems" [value]="food">
      {{food}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="searchFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table matSort mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member">{{member.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>UserName</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member">{{member.username}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member">{{member.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="buttons">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Buttons</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let member"><span (click)="hello(member.name)">Hello</span></td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Can i even create different filter for different fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to differentiate between multiple filter predicates.
For different flag run different if conditions, and try to return true from if conditions as per your requirement.

your code may look like this

```
searchIn = 0;


this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
              (data: Element, filter: string) => {
                if(searchIn == 1)
                       return data['username'].trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
              else{
                 const datasrc = data['username']+data['name']
                  return datasrc.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
             }                  
          }


applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue);
this.searchIn=1;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
  searchFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue);
this.searchIn=0;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
```

Let me know if it works, I haven't tried but i think it'll work;

Comment: @Nishant Thanks .. I was looking for this solution